# Critique my "proof" that nr of left cosets = nr of right cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Working on my first course in abstract algebra, and I would appreciate some feedback on this proof I did for a problem.

*Theorem:*

The number of left cosets in a group G is the same as the number of right cosets in G.

*Proof:*

Let $H = \{H_1,H_2,H_3.....\}$ be the set of all subgroups of G, and let $a_LH' = \{aH_1,aH_2,aH_3.....\}$ be the set of all left cosets of $H_i$ in G containing $a$, $a \in G$. Similarly, let $a_RH$ be the the set of all right cosets. Define: $$\phi(x)|a_LH \rightarrow a_RH$$ by $$\phi(x) = a^{-1}xa$$
We will show that $\phi(x)$ is a bijection.

1)  Suppose $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$. Then $$\phi(aH_i)=\phi(aH_j)$$
$$a^{-1}(aH_i)a=a^{-1}(aH_j)a$$
$$(a^{-1}a)H_ia)=(a^{-1}a)H_ja$$
$$(e)H_ia=(e)H_ja$$, where $e$ denotes the identity element, so $$H_ia=H_ja$$
so that $\phi(x),\phi(y) \in a_RH' $ and they are equal, so $\phi(x)$ is 1:1.

2) Let $H_sa$ be a given element in $a_RH$. Then by taking $x = aH_i$ which is in $a_LH$, then $$\phi(x) = \phi(aH_i) = H_ia$$ and thus $\phi(x)$ is onto. This is what we needed to prove.
$\Box$

How does this hold up? Are there any ambiguous steps, or leaps of logic that are not warrented?

Comment: You were probably asked to prove that each particular subgroup has the same number of left and right cosets, so you don't need to think about all the subgroups at once. Even if you were asked about them all, the theorem follows from its truth for each subgroup separately.

Comment: You have proved that for any particular element $a \in G$, the left cosets $aH_i$ are in a one-to-one correspondence with the right cosets $H_i a$. What you have been asked to prove is (probably) that the different left cosets $aH$ of a particular subgroup $H$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the right cosets $Ha$ of the same subgroup. Or perhaps (going by the statement you've written), you're asked to prove that the set of all left cosets (of all subgroups) is in a one-to-one correspondence with the set of all right cosets. For this, you have to prove that $aH = bH \implies Ha = Hb$ too.

Comment: But I agree with Ethan in considering this less likely, and that proving (the more likely and usual) result about the one-to-one correspondence between left and right cosets of a fixed subgroup proves the result about one-to-one correspondence between all left cosets and all right cosets.